# Conversion .dat to .mat using Python

Tags: python, matlab, file-conversion

I have a directory in which there are files with the extension .dat.
[image]
How can I quickly convert all files in this directory to .mat expansion.

Comment: Convert or rename?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Convert

Comment: Are you sure the .dat files have a format which will be read by Matlab? Because renaming is easy

Comment: @SoH: How can we help you convert the files if we don't know what format they are? There is no standard `.dat` format. We have no idea what's in them.

Comment: @gnovice How to see what is stored in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mat` files are files which contain data that can be read by Matlab. If the `.dat` files have a format that can also be read by Matlab, then your problem is a simple file renaming problem. More precisely, change the extension of all the files in a folder from `dat` to `mat`.

The code will be something like this:

```
# Python3 code to rename multiple 
# files in a directory or folder 

# importing os module 
import os 

# Function to rename multiple files 
def main(): 
    i = 0

    for filename in os.listdir("xyz"): #xyz=the folder which has your files
        dst ="s0" + str(i) + "lre.mat" #I suppose the numbering of the files begins with 0. This is the name pattern I detected from your screenshot
        src ='xyz'+ filename 
        dst ='xyz'+ dst 

        # rename() function will 
        # rename all the files 
        os.rename(src, dst) 
        i += 1

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling main() function 
    main()
```